# MongoDB Date Type: Casting fails

Tags: mongodb, date

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
    ...
    expireAt: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    ...
});
```

If I use this Schema everything works but If I set a more complex default like this:

```
var MySchema = new Schema({
    ...
    expireAt: { type: Date, default: ( Date.now + 1000 )},
    ...
});
```

On the creation the following error is shown:

> CastError: Cast to date faile for value "function now() .....

I tried to keep out the value but still problem with casting

```
var t = Date.now + 1000;
var MySchema = new Schema({
    ...
    expireAt: { type: Date, default: t},
    ...
});
```

Also tried with `new Date()`... but now way.

I need this field to be check for the expireAt for TTL so I think I can't set a different type from `Date`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can set expires in your created field in schema like:

```
new Schema({ createdAt: { type: Date, expires: 60*60*24 }});
```

the document created with above code will expired after 24 hrs.

Comment: Actually I want that the whole Object will be removed and not only the field

Comment: Yes it will remove the whole document.

Comment: I tried but it seems not working. I set `expireAt: { type: Date, expires: 60 } `on my schema and keep the `MySchema.index( { "expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } );` . After 60seconds the record was still there in my database.

Comment: You don't need to specify MySchema.index( { "expireAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 0 } ); just set schema and first drop index from your db (run command db.getCollection.dropIndexes()) after that run the server. the index will create automatically.

Comment: So if I understood well the documents are deleted only at the startup of the server?

Comment: If yes, it is not what I'm looking for